Recommendations for a PMG generator driver motor
A year ago, I installed a 10kW hybrid solar inverter for my house. However, due to insufficient sunlight, the solar panels have not been very effective for me. To address this issue, I am planning to install a 10kW permanent magnet generator with a 1HP, 1400 RPM AC motor for support. The concern I have is that the PMG generator runs at 500 RPM, and I am worried it might lead to overvoltage. Do you have any advice for me? I am considering using a VFD. Is it okay to try it without the VFD?
Thanks in advance.
I plan to use a 10 kW permanent magnet generator (PMG) driven by an AC motor, with a hybrid inverter managing the system and an automatic transfer switch (ATS) between the utility power and the PMG.

When utility power is available, the hybrid inverter will bypass the battery and operate directly on utility power.
When utility power is lost, the system will switch to the DC battery through the hybrid inverter, though the battery lasts only about an hour. To extend this, I plan to connect the PMG to the ATS, which will switch from utility power to the PMG when the utility is down, allowing the system to run longer using the generator.
Since the AC motor powering the PMG needs AC power, it will get this power from the hybrid inverter, even without utility supply.

In summary, the idea is to use the hybrid inverter's DC battery to power the AC motor, which will drive the PMG to generate additional electricity. This forms a loop where the inverter powers the motor, the motor drives the generator, and the generator feeds power back into the system.

Not sure I understand- You're going to try to run a 10 kW generator with a 1 HP AC motor? Then use that to power your inverter, as kind of an M-G set? What's the purpose? Why can't you use the AC that's powering the motor directly?  Maybe a diagram of what you're trying to do might help clear things up.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The simple solution is to use some form of reduction - belt & pulleys, chain and sprockets or maybe a Harmonic drive. you need a reduction just slightly less than 3:1. Make it 3:1 and that takes care of the phase multiplication - 1 phase to three phase.


In summary, the idea is to use the hybrid inverter's DC battery to power the AC motor, which will drive the PMG to generate additional electricity. This forms a loop where the inverter powers the motor, the motor drives the generator, and the generator feeds power back into the system.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Self-powering system.

Let's say the generator is 60% efficient. (You are driving it with a 1 HP (= 750 W) motor so you are nowhere near the generator's optimum operation point.) With 750 W mechanical input you will get 750 x 0.6 = 450 W electrical out.
Let's say your motor is 80% efficient. To output 750 W mechanical to drive the generator the motor will draw 750 / 0.8 = 940 W from the inverter.
Let's say the inverter is 85% efficient. To supply 940 W to the motor it will draw 940 / 0.85 = 1100 W from the battery.

So far you have generated 450 W at a cost of 1100 W. If you were to scrap the motor and generator you would get 940 W for a cost of 1100 W but that's still a loss.
You can't create energy out of nothing.

What are your thoughts on this? I’m in the process of trying to build it. Just found this amazing item on AliExpress. Check it out! US $670.33 | High Efficiency 30KW 96V 110V 120V 220V 380V 3Phase Alternator Motor Permanent Magnet Rare Earth Turbine Generator For Homeuse
https://a.aliexpress.com/_EQlQnD3

What are you asking? Do I think that this motor/generator will be able to defy the laws of physics and give out more power than you put in? What do you think is amazing about it?

If it really produces more power than you put in, as claimed, don’t you think it’s fascinating? I’ve always believed that free energy isn’t possible, but I think it’s worth trying.

Where do you read that it produces more power than you put in?

My professor told me the same thing as you, but I contacted the company, and they said it can generate 10 kW with very low RPM and an AC governor. They even sent me a video of their test, but I’m not sure how to share it here! However, there are plenty of videos on YouTube from the Liberty Engine project.

You know that if you switch to a high gear on your bike that you can achieve the same speed at low RPM but you'll have to input more torque from your legs. Low RPM x HIgh Torque = High RPM x Low Torque. Power Out = Power In - Efficiency Losses. Their claim is meaningless.

I've already purchased the PMG generator, so now I'll just look for the AC motor. Once I have it, I'll give it a try and share the results.

I can write the report for you now. Don't be silly! If what you are proposing was possible it would be available commercially and all power for a country would be generated by a hamster on a wheel driving a series of motor generators to step up the power output.

I completely agree with you, and I truly believe in what you're saying. I just hope this dream becomes a reality.
https://youtube.com/shorts/TG2jeuDTm2s?si=n9FLoFyu7TFMalWc

Lovely video and machining. Ask yourself how does that system start up and accelerate itself up to 50 Hz (or 60 Hz) and stabilise at that frequency and stabilise the voltage at 230 V when there is no governor or voltage regulator. There is a mains power supply input somewhere. Also silver and aluminium are not ferromagnetic so the generator would have huge "air" gaps and be very inefficient.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbdU7AkH6QM&ab_channel=JeremyFielding.
